# How to add categories in shopify blog like wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, shopify, blogs

[I want categories like this in Shopify blog section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qln9S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `blog-sidebar`  section and associate on blog page.

1. Navigate to section and add a template name blog-sidebar.liquid
2. include a sidebar on blog page

   {% section 'blog-template' %}
         
         
       {% section 'blog-sidebar' %}
3. on `blog-sidebar.liquid` add a schema like below which would add a
   textarea field to list tags that we are considering as a blog
   category

   {% schema %}
     {
       "name": "Sidebar",
       "settings": [
         {
           "type": "textarea",
           "id": "blog_category",
           "label": "Blog category",
       "info": "categories are selective tags. Mention those selective tags seperated with comma above."
         }
       ]
     }
   {% endschema %}
4. The above schema on blog-sidebar section would create a field on
   blog section on `customize theme`. (Online store > customize theme >
   navigate to blog page on the preview section to view)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxDrb.jpg)

5. Now add tags that you are considering as blog categories separated
   with comma, in the above screenshot `summer` and `another` are tags.
6. on the same blog-sidebar section add these codes

   {% comment %}
         Blog categories
       {% endcomment %}
       {% if blog.all_tags.size > 0 %}
         {{ 'blogs.sidebar.categories' | t }}
         
           {% for tag in blog.all_tags %}
               {% if section.settings.blog_category contains tag %}  
                 {% if current_tags contains tag %}

   {{ tag }}

   {% else %}

   {{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}

   {% endif %}
               {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
         
       {% endif %}

The code above would print tags that we have separated as categories.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using tags? @Manmeet Kaur